# How to get the SUM of the final score in an Elastic Search query_string request?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to convert my Elastic Search query to SUM the score at the end rather than get the MAX value?

My request is similar to the following (I typed it out and there may be errors):

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "query_string":
        {
            "query": "example",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "phrase_slop": 1,
            "fields": ["field1^3", "field2^2", "field3^1"]
        }
    },
    "explain": true,
    "track_scores": true,
    "sort": [{"_score": "desc"}]
}
```

The explanation in the response says "max of".

I've tried adding 'score_mode':'sum', but that doesn't seem to work for me. I'm obviously not using it properly.

Help!

Comment: If you're happy with only producing matches when all of your search terms occur in a single field (e.g all of your search terms are in field1), then it sounds like `type: "most_fields"`might be what you are after rather than `cross_fields`. It would be worth exploring the Elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types) and updating this question to clarify what you want your matching logic to be.

Comment: I definitely want cross_fields. The question explains everything that I need. It searches multiple fields, gets the value for each field after matching (eg. field1 = 3, field3 = 1) and then adds them together (eg. 3 + 1 = 4). At the moment it's giving the maximum value found for each field (eg. 3 since field1 = 3 and it matched).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [tie_breaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#tie-breaker) parameter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      ...
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "tie_breaker": 1.0,
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Paraphrasing the linked documentation:

> By default, each query will use the best score returned by any field in a group, then these scores are added together to give the final score. The `tie_breaker` parameter can change the default behaviour of the queries. It accepts:
>
> **0.0** Take the single best field score (default)
>
> **1.0** Add together the field scores

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks @avik!

Answer (score 0):

You would try to use a calculate score. Take a look here in the last example:

https://qbox.io/blog/scoring-using-elasticsearch-scripts-part1?utm_source=qbox.io&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=practical-guide-elasticsearch-scoring-relevancy

Comment: I've tried that but I can't find a solution that works with query_string. Do you have an example?